# bigquery got multiple values for keyword argument 'project'

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect with Google BigQuery but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR api Query failure: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'project'
```

This is how I'm doing:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY = dotenv.get_key(dotenv_path, 'CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY')

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY, 'project-id123')
```

CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY is his json:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "roas-xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxx",
  "private_key": "xxxxn-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/cxxxerts",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix a small error

```
bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_BIGQUERY, project='project-id123')
```

This problem is the from_service_account_json function accept only 1 not named argument all other arguments should be passed as named